# Make element fade in on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently managed to make a toggle audio button for my website but want it to fade in and with the scroll to top button I have on my website (which functions exactly the same as the buttons on [scrolltotop.com](http://www.scrolltotop.com/)). Is there any easy way to do this?

Below is the HTML I have so far:

```
  <div id='cornerplayer'>
<center>
  <div id='cornericon'></div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <img src=http://www.thegeekypixel.com/files/theme/Images/noaudio.png onclick="javascript:toggleSound();this.src = this.src == offImg ? onImg : offImg;">
  <audio id="audio" loop>
    <source src="http://www.thegeekypixel.com/files/theme/Music/TellMe-Killercatsfeat.AlexSkrindo.mp3">
  </audio>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleSound() {
      var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
      if (audioElem.paused)
        audioElem.play();
      else
        audioElem.pause();
    }
    var onImg = "http://www.thegeekypixel.com/files/theme/Images/noaudio.png";
    var offImg = "http://www.thegeekypixel.com/files/theme/Images/audioplaying.png";

  </script>
  </div>
  </center>
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

[This is what I managed to get on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/71uncr2g/)

The button which I am trying to get to fade in is a "cornerplayer" button which plays music whenever the button is clicked and floats in the bottom right hand corner of the screen.

Is there any easy way to be able to get this to fade in in time with the scroll to top button?

Thanks,
Oliver

Also, sorry for any error. I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollCheck(element) {
    var top = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var bottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if((top >= 0) && (bottom <= window.innerHeight)) {
        fadeIn(element)
    }
}

function fadeIn(element) {
    var op = 0.1
    rate = 0.1
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (op >= 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        op += op * rate;
    },50);
};
```

Call function `scrollCheck` repeatedly to check if the user has scrolled down to the specified element. If (s)he has, `scrollCheck` will call `fadeIn` to fade in your element.

In other words, use `scrollCheck(document.getElementById("element"))` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.onscroll` event and check for the `scrollY` property, like this:

```
var h = window.innerHeight; // calculate this only once to avoid redraws
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var scrollH = window.scrollY,
      ratio = parseFloat(scrollH / h), // current scroll percentage vs. page height
      benchmark = parseInt(ratio) % 10 === 0; // update opacity only every 10%
  if (benchmark)
    document.getElementById('cornericon').style.opacity = ratio;
}
```

See an updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/71uncr2g/1/